# How to merge old workspace into new ros version

Tags: ros-jade, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In the past I worked on ROS Indigo, but I wanted to upgrade to Jade, so I removed Indigo and installed jade (fully).
but now I have a problem, my previous work is only visible to ROS if I use `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`.
So how do I merge or upgrade that directory from a indigo to a Jade one.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244312/how-to-merge-old-workspace-into-new-ros-version/) by [JoostW](https://answers.ros.org/users/27844/joostw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-09-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-09-23**:
Is "your previous work" somehow located inside of `/opt/ros/indigo`? Or is it in a workspace that you've been using with Indigo?

**Comment by [JoostW](https://answers.ros.org/users/27844/joostw/) on 2016-09-23**:
it was a workspace I was using with Indigo. And the directory is still in the same place on my hard-drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the answer myself.

My old workspace wasn't in my `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.
So with the simple command `source devel/setup.bash` (and a few hours headache) all of my former projects are working again in ROS Jade.

---

Originally posted by [JoostW](https://answers.ros.org/users/27844/joostw/) with karma: 26 on 2016-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1